# Setting up Dirac Devtools for clojurescript

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, clojurescript

steps taken to setup

```
% git clone https://github.com/binaryage/dirac-sample.git
% cd dirac-sample
% lein demo
```

in another console:

```
% cd dirac-sample
% lein repl
...
user=> 
Dirac Agent v1.2.17
Connected to nREPL server at nrepl://localhost:8230.
Agent is accepting connections at ws://localhost:8231.
```

Open Chromium with command:

```
% /usr/bin/chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-first-run --user-data-dir=~/.dirac
```

Dirac Devtools already installed to this Chromium

In Chromium open page:

```
http://localhost:9977
```

When there click on the 'Click to open Dirac Devtools' green squiggly
line icon.

Devtools is opened with the green underline highlight not blue.

On webpage click on 'demo a breakpoint'

Nothing shows up in the green underline hightlight devtools, but a
'Paused in Debugger' overlay is on the webpage.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong